# Can't find project or library on RegExp

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I am running a macro in VBA that uses regular expressions. I moved a template to a new computer.

When I try to run the project, I get an Error

> Can't find project or library"`

and the line

`If re Is Nothing Then Set re = New RegExp"`

is highlighted.

When I open the references, it shows that `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` has been ticked.

Not sure where the issue is coming from. Need some guidance on this.

Comment: Is that reference shown with 'MISSING:' at the start?

Comment: There isn't any. But there is a UNSAVED: VBAProject

Comment: If `VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` checked then you should able to create a `RegExp object` to use in your VBA eg: `Dim regEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line:

```
If re Is Nothing Then Set re = New RegExp
```

To this:

```
If re Is Nothing Then Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
```

Also remember to declare the `re` variable properly:

```
Dim re as Object
```

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` on? Maybe you need to declare `Dim re as Object`. If you declared `re` in your code this is probably the case.

Comment: re is defined as such : Static re As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

Comment: Change `VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp` to `Object`

Comment: still the same issue.

Comment: Which line now? The `Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")`?

Comment: Static re As Object Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"). It is pointing to the first line

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with the dll `C:\Windows\System32\vbscript.dll`? Try my code above on a fresh XLSM file. If it fails try to fix the vbscript.dll

Comment: If you get an error on `Static re as Object` I think you have bigger problems than references. Do you have any activex controls on worksheets?

Comment: I didnot add the analysis pak addin into my Excel Add-Ins.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this until I noticed that `New rexExp` was being auto-corrected to `New RegExp`! The below worked for me, note the lower-case r in `regExp`:

```
Dim regEx As Object
Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.regExp")
```